# How to get values of an Array inside another array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to get values of an array which is inside another array using php.
I tried to get city of the address and write the following line
`print_r($store_info[address[2]);` but getting nothing

My Array is

```
$store_info= Array ( [phone] => +918886330242 [address] => Array ( [street_1] => Plot no 19, Dr. Sundaraiah Colony, [street_2] => Picket, Secunderabad [city] => Hyderabad [zip] => 500003 [country] => IN [state] => TS ) [location] => [banner] => 8361 [icon] => 0 [gravatar] => 0 [show_more_ptab] => yes [store_ppp] => 10 [enable_tnc] => off [store_tnc] => [show_min_order_discount] => no [store_seo] => Array ( [dokan-seo-meta-title] => Online Grocery Store Hyderabad [dokan-seo-meta-desc] => Online Grocery Store in Hyderabad / Secunderabad is one of the best online grocery store for wholesale and retail [dokan-seo-meta-keywords] => [dokan-seo-og-title] => [dokan-seo-og-desc] => [dokan-seo-og-image] => 0 [dokan-seo-twitter-title] => [dokan-seo-twitter-desc] => [dokan-seo-twitter-image] => 0 ) [find_address] => [dokan_store_time] => Array ( [sunday] => Array ( [open] => close [opening_time] => [closing_time] => ) [monday] => Array ( [open] => close [opening_time] => [closing_time] => ) [tuesday] => Array ( [open] => close [opening_time] => [closing_time] => ) [wednesday] => Array ( [open] => close [opening_time] => [closing_time] => ) [thursday] => Array ( [open] => close [opening_time] => [closing_time] => ) [friday] => Array ( [open] => close [opening_time] => [closing_time] => ) [saturday] => Array ( [open] => close [opening_time] => [closing_time] => ) ) [dokan_store_time_enabled] => no [dokan_store_open_notice] => [dokan_store_close_notice] => [profile_completion] => Array ( [phone] => 10 [banner] => 15 [store_name] => 10 [address] => 10 [Bank] => 15 [next_todo] => Add Profile Picture to gain 15% progress [progress] => 60 [progress_vals] => Array ( [banner_val] => 15 [profile_picture_val] => 15 [store_name_val] => 10 [social_val] => Array ( [fb] => 2 [gplus] => 2 [twitter] => 2 [youtube] => 2 [linkedin] => 2 ) [payment_method_val] => 15 [phone_val] => 10 [address_val] => 10 [map_val] => 15 ) ) [setting_minimum_order_amount] => [setting_order_percentage] => [support_btn_name] => [show_support_btn] => yes )
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please use `var_export()` when providing your sample data.  Using code block formatting will make your question easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keys directly as they all are associative arrays:

```
$city = $store_info['address']['city'];

var_dump($city);
```